Align 3 tables neatly
I have three tables and I would like to align 2 horizontally with each other and the third below. How can I do?

This is my LaTeX overleaf code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}[h!]
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.35\textwidth} > {\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.35\textwidth}}

    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c |c |}
    \hline
    \textbf{Impiegato} & \textbf{Stipendio} \\
    \hline
    Rossi & 20 000 \\
    Verdi & 35 000 \\
    Neri & 55 000 \\
    Mori & 48 000 \\
    Bianchi & 48 000 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} &
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c |c |}
    \hline
    \textbf{Progetto} & \textbf{Bilancio} \\
    \hline
    Marte & 2 000 \\
    Giove & 15 000 \\
    Venere & 15 000 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage} \\[6em] 

 \multicolumn{2}{c}{
    \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c |c | c |}
        \hline
        \textbf{Impiegato} & \textbf{Progetto} & \textbf{Funzione} \\
        \hline
        Rossi & Marte & Tecnico \\
        Verdi & Giove & Progettista \\
        Verdi & Venere & Progettista \\
        Neri & Venere & Direttore \\
        Neri & Giove & Consulente \\
        Neri & Marte & Consulente \\
        Mori & Marte & Direttore \\
        Mori & Venere & Progettista \\
        Bianchi & Venere & Progettista \\
        Bianchi & Giove & Direttore \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
}
 \end{tabular}
  \caption{Esempio di relazione con anomalie.}
 \label{relazione_con_anomalie}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}


Can you specify how you want to align the tables? Top, bottom, center?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz in the middle

They already seem to be aligned in the middle?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes, but the third table is not aligned in the middle compared to the two tables above. It is placed further to the right than the two. And also I think the code is slightly wrong; in fact it tells me: Overfull \hbox (2.56543 pt too wide)

The outer tabular seems unnecessarily complicate, you could directly place the two inner tables besides each other:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}[h!]
 \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c |c |}
    \hline
    \textbf{Impiegato} & \textbf{Stipendio} \\
    \hline
    Rossi & 20 000 \\
    Verdi & 35 000 \\
    Neri & 55 000 \\
    Mori & 48 000 \\
    Bianchi & 48 000 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \quad
    \begin{tabular}{|c |c |}
    \hline
    \textbf{Progetto} & \textbf{Bilancio} \\
    \hline
    Marte & 2 000 \\
    Giove & 15 000 \\
    Venere & 15 000 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
  
  \bigskip
  
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c |c | c |}
        \hline
        \textbf{Impiegato} & \textbf{Progetto} & \textbf{Funzione} \\
        \hline
        Rossi & Marte & Tecnico \\
        Verdi & Giove & Progettista \\
        Verdi & Venere & Progettista \\
        Neri & Venere & Direttore \\
        Neri & Giove & Consulente \\
        Neri & Marte & Consulente \\
        Mori & Marte & Direttore \\
        Mori & Venere & Progettista \\
        Bianchi & Venere & Progettista \\
        Bianchi & Giove & Direttore \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
  \caption{Esempio di relazione con anomalie.}
 \label{relazione_con_anomalie}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}



I'd typeset the two short and narrow tables one on top of the other and the longer table side-by-side.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

 \begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c |c |}
  \hline
  \textbf{Impiegato} & \textbf{Stipendio} \\
  \hline
  Rossi & 20\,000 \\
  Verdi & 35\,000 \\
  Neri & 55\,000 \\
  Mori & 48\,000 \\
  Bianchi & 48\,000 \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}

\\ \\

  \begin{tabular}{|c |c |}
  \hline
  \textbf{Progetto} & \textbf{Bilancio} \\
  \hline
  Marte & 2\,000 \\
  Giove & 15\,000 \\
  Venere & 15\,000 \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}\hfil
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c |c | c |}
\hline
\textbf{Impiegato} & \textbf{Progetto} & \textbf{Funzione} \\
\hline
Rossi & Marte & Tecnico \\
Verdi & Giove & Progettista \\
Verdi & Venere & Progettista \\
Neri & Venere & Direttore \\
Neri & Giove & Consulente \\
Neri & Marte & Consulente \\
Mori & Marte & Direttore \\
Mori & Venere & Progettista \\
Bianchi & Venere & Progettista \\
Bianchi & Giove & Direttore \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Esempio di relazione con anomalie.}
\label{relazione_con_anomalie}

\end{table}

\end{document}


With some trickery it would be possible to shorten the space between the tables on the left to match the height of the table on the right. I did not attempt, because this decision has to be made by seeing the actual tables.
With a different style and equalizing the width of the two tables on the left:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  
\begin{tabular*}{0.3\textwidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cc@{}}
\toprule
Impiegato & Stipendio \\
\midrule
  Rossi & 20\,000 \\
  Verdi & 35\,000 \\
  Neri & 55\,000 \\
  Mori & 48\,000 \\
  Bianchi & 48\,000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\\ \\

\begin{tabular*}{0.3\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cc@{}}
\toprule
Progetto & Bilancio \\
\midrule
  Marte & 2\,000 \\
  Giove & 15\,000 \\
  Venere & 15\,000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{tabular}\hfil
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc@{}}
\toprule
Impiegato & Progetto & Funzione \\
\midrule
Rossi & Marte & Tecnico \\
Verdi & Giove & Progettista \\
Verdi & Venere & Progettista \\
Neri & Venere & Direttore \\
Neri & Giove & Consulente \\
Neri & Marte & Consulente \\
Mori & Marte & Direttore \\
Mori & Venere & Progettista \\
Bianchi & Venere & Progettista \\
Bianchi & Giove & Direttore \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Esempio di relazione con anomalie.}
\label{relazione_con_anomalie}

\end{table}

\end{document}



Some observations, in no particular order:

No need for "outer" tabular or minipage environments.

A single \centering instruction suffices.

I would top-align the first two tables.

I would left-align rather than center the contents of text-material cells.

No need for bold-facing of the header rows.

Do align the numbers in the data columns on their (implicit) decimal markers. I suggest you do so with the help of the siunitx package and its S column type.

Do give the tables a more open and inviting "look" by (a) getting rid of all vertical lines and (b) using the line-drawing macros of the booktabs package instead of \hline.



\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\sisetup{table-format=5.0,group-minimum-digits=4}
\centering

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l S @{}}
\toprule
Impiegato & {Stipendio} \\
\midrule
    Rossi   & 20000 \\
    Verdi   & 35000 \\
    Neri    & 55000 \\
    Mori    & 48000 \\
    Bianchi & 48000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l S @{}}
\toprule
Progetto & {Bilancio} \\
\midrule
    Marte  &  2000 \\
    Giove  & 15000 \\
    Venere & 15000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} lll @{}}
\toprule
Impiegato & Progetto & Funzione \\
\midrule
        Rossi & Marte  & Tecnico     \\
        Verdi & Giove  & Progettista \\
        Verdi & Venere & Progettista \\
        Neri  & Venere & Direttore   \\
        Neri  & Giove  & Consulente  \\
        Neri  & Marte  & Consulente  \\
        Mori  & Marte  & Direttore   \\
        Mori  & Venere & Progettista \\
        Bianchi & Venere & Progettista \\
        Bianchi & Giove & Direttore  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Esempio di relazione con anomalie.}
\label{relazione_con_anomalie}
\end{table}

\end{document}

